# Checking Relative Parent Folder File in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am running a batch file in `src` folder. `build` folder is one level up. I wanted to check if the `compiled.exe` is already in build folder or not.

```
set "compiledFile=%~dp0..\build\compiled.exe"
IF EXIST %compiledFile% (
    echo compiled
) ELSE (
    echo not compiled
)
```

Using the code, weirdly, the `IF` and `ELSE` cases both echo to the console.

What is wrong with the code and how can I check if the `compiled.exe` exists in `build` folder?

Comment: Enclose the full path name in quotes: `IF EXIST "%compiledFile%" (`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
IF EXIST ..\build\compiled.exe
```